# Woocommerce - load Jquery function on init and after register button click

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce

I add this custom code for woocommerce registration process. I have 2 select fields. Practically if you select an option in the first select, exactly the same option is selected in the second select field.

The problem is that when the page loads it works, but when I click on register, the url changes like this: /my-account/?action=register and the Js doesn't work anymore.

I think because the javascript is loaded immediately and then if a change occurs it no longer works, how can I make it work even when you click the register button?

```html
<?php
  add_action('woocommerce_register_form', 'conditionally_hidding_billing_company', 10, 0);

  function conditionally_hidding_billing_company() { ?>
    <script>
      jQuery(function ($) {             
        $('#afreg_select_user_role').change(function() {
          var val = $('#afreg_select_user_role').prop('selectedIndex');
          $("#wcb2b_group").prop('selectedIndex', val);
        });
      });
    </script>
  <?php }
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need a delegated event handler, change `$('#afreg_select_user_role').change(function () {` to `$(document).on('change', '#afreg_select_user_role', function () {`

Comment: Nothing change.

Comment: did you close php tag in `function conditionally_hidding_billing_company() { ?>` line? did you see `$('#afreg_select_user_role').change..`  in `/my-account/?action=register` page?

Comment: Yes, it works only on load page. When I click on register button stop working.